# Save MySQL query results into a text file

Tags: mysql

I want to save a MySQL query result to to a text file like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders INTO OUTFILE '/data.txt'
```

However, I don't have write permission on the server. Where can I write to or is there a simpler way?

Comment: mysql -h<mysqlhostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> -e "select * from orders" > myfile.txt ;;;
-p means you'll get to enter your password before seeing the results. I assume that you will run this command from the directory where you have the right to create files.

Comment: @ChrisLively It will be good if I could write to Dropbox. But where can I specify my account of Dropbox in the INTO clause? Thanks.

Comment: Don´t you have access to temp directory? What is the operating system?

Comment: What type of server is it? Do you have any web scripting languages on it? If for example you have ASP or PHP you can create a page that just prints out the recordset. Then this file will be accessible from anywhere you choose as a "file" eg: http://www.example.com/myrecordset.php will be a file with your query result.

Comment: you can do "tee /tmp/logfile.out" in mysql, everthing done in mysql will reflect in the file.

Comment: you can use any extension for it, or dont use extension at all "tee /tmp/logfile"

Answer (score 11):

use this command:

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "select * from database_name.table_name" > filename.txt
```

Enter the password and all is done

Answer (score 6):

```
select * into outfile  'sd1.txt' from orders;
```

or

```
select * into outfile  'sd1.sql' from orders;
```

Comment: Thanks. that saved me. i just created sql using your method to copy over some corrupted db values as `mysql -uuser -p database -e "SELECT concat('update core_config_data set value=\'',value,'\'',' where path=\'',path,'\';') as sql_update FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%paypal%'" > paypal.sql` but not sure why I'm getting NULL row after every few sql_update statement rows. But that's not an issue as I can manually remove them before running to another database. But would be good to know some tips to remove them from output :)

Comment: @Damodar Bashyal ---- >Actually i didn't get what u are asking..? i think u want to update then save the changes into file like that...!!!  update core_config_data set value='value' where path='path'; select * into paypal.sql core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%paypal%'"